# Problema con Gridview al girar la pantalla

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

Hola Gente Estoy trabajando con GRIDVIEW en una app ,tengo un problema al cuando giro la pantalla(el landscape) me cambia de lugar las imagines o me las duplica no se porque , ahi esta mi codigo

```
 GridView androidGridView;
String scanneo;
EditText etSacnner;
String[] gridViewString = {
        "Capturar", "Pedidos ", "Canasto", "Stock", "Salir"};
int[] gridViewImageId = {
        R.drawable.qr,
        R.drawable.pedidos,
        R.drawable.canasto,
        R.drawable.stock,
        R.drawable.logoff};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_inicio);
    etSacnner=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBuscarArt);

    //CustomGridViewActivity adapter = new CustomGridViewActivity(MenuInicio.this, gridViewString, gridViewImageId);
    androidGridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    androidGridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridViewActivity(this, gridViewString,gridViewImageId));
    androidGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int i, long id) {
            if(gridViewString[+i].equals("Scanear")){


            }

            Toast.makeText(MenuInicio.this, "GridView Item: " + gridViewString[+i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

muchas GRacias 
ahi esta mi clase adapter

```
   private Context mContext;
private final String[] gridViewString;
private final int[] gridViewImageId;

public CustomGridViewActivity(Context context, String[] gridViewString, int[] gridViewImageId) {
    mContext = context;
    this.gridViewImageId = gridViewImageId;
    this.gridViewString = gridViewString;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return gridViewString.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridViewAndroid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridViewAndroid = new View(mContext);
        gridViewAndroid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);
        TextView textViewAndroid = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_title);
        ImageView imageViewAndroid = (ImageView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        textViewAndroid.setText(gridViewString[i]);
        imageViewAndroid.setImageResource(gridViewImageId[i]);
    } else {
        gridViewAndroid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridViewAndroid;
}
```

y  las capturas de pantalla antes y despues
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
despues de girar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes mostrar una imagen de como se ven en ambos modos(landscape y portrait)?

Comment: Puedes agregar el código del adaptador y una captura de pantalla de como queda el gridView, al girar el cell.

Comment: @David,@Einer muchas gracias por su apoyo ,lo edite  a la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

La vista se debe reutilizar en el `Adapter` pero las propiedades deben cambiar, realiza este cambio en tu método `getView()` del Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridViewAndroid;
    TextView textViewAndroid; 
    ImageView imageViewAndroid;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridViewAndroid = new View(mContext);
        gridViewAndroid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);
        textViewAndroid = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_title);
        imageViewAndroid = (ImageView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

    } else {
        gridViewAndroid = (View) convertView;
    }

       //*Cambia propiedades  en las vistas.
       textViewAndroid.setText(gridViewString[i]);
       imageViewAndroid.setImageResource(gridViewImageId[i]);

    return gridViewAndroid;
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias maestro funciona muy bien , y tu codigo me ayudo a entender mi error GRACIAS

Comment: @user62207 que bien solucionaste tu problema, solo estabas cambiando las propiedades cuando creabas por primera ocasión la vista. Por cierto edite la respuesta, la definición de variables: TextView textViewAndroid; 
    ImageView imageViewAndroid; debe ser afuera del "if", saludos!

Comment: sii  los habias declarado desde afuera los TextView  GRACIAS